# How to POST binary data in request using request library?

Tags: javascript, post, binary, request, requestjs

I have to send binary contents of a remote file to an API endpoint. I read the binary contents of remote file using [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and store it in a variable. Now with contents in the variable ready to be sent, how do I post it to remote api using request library.

What I have currently and doesn't work is:

```
const makeWitSpeechRequest = (audioBinary) => {
  request({
    url: 'https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20160526',
    method: 'POST',
    body: audioBinary,
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error sending message: ', error)
    } else {
      console.log('Response: ', response.body)
    }
  })
}
```

We can safely assume here that `audioBinary` has binary contents that were read from a remote file.

**What do I mean when I say it doesn't work?**
The payload shows up different in request debugging.
Actual binary payload: `ID3TXXXmajor_brandisomTXXXminor_version512TXXX`
Payload showed in debugging: `ID3\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0006TXXX\u0000\u0000\u0000\`

**What works in Terminal?**
What I know works from Terminal is with a difference that it reads the contents of file too in the same command:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20160526' \
      -i -L \
      --data-binary "@hello.mp3"
```

Comment: Did you get any success ?

Comment: Yes, I'll post an answer here. The answer was in the documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option in request library to send binary data as such is `encoding: null`. The default value of encoding is `string` so contents by default get converted to `utf-8`.

So the correct way to send binary data in the above example would be:

```
const makeWitSpeechRequest = (audioBinary) => {
  request({
    url: 'https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20160526',
    method: 'POST',
    body: audioBinary,
    encoding: null
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
       console.log('Error sending message: ', error)
    } else {
      console.log('Response: ', response.body)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Also make sure that the `json` property in the options passed to the request isn't set to `true` as this will override the `encoding: null` and cause the body to be treated as text.

Comment: It worked without setting `encoding: null` in my case. Note that setting `encoding: null` returns binary response.

Comment: How do you read that file? `fs.createReadStream('path-to-file', { encoding: 'binary' })` or something else?